# android: listActivity under Tab

Tags: android, listview, tabs, listactivity

Sorry if this is a repeat, none of the solutions I found online worked for me.

I have 2 tabs, and I'm trying to add a list unto one of the tabs. Here's the code:

```
public class Library extends ListActivity {

    ParsingDBHelper mDbHelper;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String temp = extra.getString(Httpdwld.RESULT);

        mDbHelper = new ParsingDBHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        parsing();

        fillData();
    }    

    private void parsing() {
        // IMPLEMENT
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllSearch();
        String[] FROM = new String[] {ParsingDBHelper.KEY_TITLE, ParsingDBHelper.KEY_AUTHOR,
                ParsingDBHelper.KEY_YEAR, ParsingDBHelper.KEY_LOCATION, 
                ParsingDBHelper.KEY_CALL_ISBN, ParsingDBHelper.KEY_AVAILABILITY};
        int[] TO = new int[] {R.id.row_title, R.id.row_author, R.id.row_year, 
                R.id.row_location, R.id.row_id, R.id.row_avail};
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, c, FROM, TO);
        lv.setAdapter(notes);
    }
}
```

mDbHelper is simply a a helper for using SQLiteDatabase.

Here's my XML code for the Tabs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" >               
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>>
</TabHost>
```

But I keep getting "Cannot start Activity: Library" error. Here's where I call Library

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_result);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(this, Library.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Library").setIndicator("Library")
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity must by listed in your AndroidManifest.xml. Your logcat would also show that as an exception.